# Error when typing cmd grunt jshint.

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, gruntjs

I am currently going to the Learn how to Program with Steve Foote. I am using ubuntu as the operating system.I have installed Node.js, installed the grunt command-line, and installed the npm install to the correct folder. 
I noticed a problem that when I ran node on the specified folder it wouldn't run the js files I have. I even went to the folder with the js files and it didn't work. I then tried node values.js but nothing came up.

This is my code for the package.json file:

```
   {
      "name": "kittenbook",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "devDependencies": {
        "grunt": "^0.4.5",
        "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
        "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.5.0",
        "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.3"
      }
   }
```

And this is the Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
//Project Configuiration
grunt.initConfig({
   /*
    * We will configuire our tasks here
   */
   concat: {
      release: {
          src:['js/values.js', 'js/prompt.js'],
          dest: 'release/main.js'
      }
   },

  copy: {
     release{
         src: 'manifest.json',
         dest: 'release/manifest.json'
     }
  },

  jshint: {
     files: ['js/values.js', 'js/prompt.js']
  } 

 });

 //We will load our plugins here
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');

 //We will register our tasks here
 grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'concat', 'copy']);
};
```

Sorry if the formatting is bad here it genuinely is all lined up on the text file.

When I type  grunt jshint a warning comes up saying:

```
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
Warning: Task "jshint" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Meaning, what command do you expect to run, and what do you expect its output to be?

Comment: When I type the command node a prompt comes up. but it should run the javafiles I have. When I type prompt.js into the prompt it gives me this as an error:
          'ReferenceError: prompt is not defined'

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a colon (:) in your grunt.initConfig object.

`copy: {
     release{ /*<--Missing colon in between "release" and the opening bracket {*/
         src: 'manifest.json',
         dest: 'release/manifest.json'
     }
  },`